# Deprecating an old link

Tags: discussion, editing, hyperlinks

This question comes from this list of edits: https://mathoverflow.net/posts/86827/revisions

An old answer included a link to a now-deprecated website (which has been taken over by a porn website); a proposed edit simply removed the deprecated website. I thought it would be better to keep the name of the website, but to note it was deprecated and remove the link, in order to preserve the intent of the original answer.

Searching for information on the old site, it seems to be a reindexing of arxiv (https://www.crossref.org/blog/eprintweb.org/), so it may not be necessary to list.

So which version is better? Alternatively, how should this be handled?

Comment: I think moving the name (and not the link) into a comment is an option explaining that it no longer is suitable. Here is a archived page that explains what happened: https://web.archive.org/web/20150202205546/http://eprintweb.org/S/ One could also give a link to https://web.archive.org/web/20130803071935/http://eprintweb.org/S/ and perhaps also to that crossref blog post.

Comment: Perhaps ([meta-tag:editing]) and ([meta-tag:specific-answer]) could be suitable tags for this question. (I'll leave it here in the comments, so that others can decide on the choice of tags. And I am very well aware that this is not too important.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I added the editing tag; this is related to a specific answer, but I think is a general question - what to do with deprecated links.

Comment: I agree that your way of handling it is perfectly reasonable, and also with @DavidRoberts's suggestion (for users without edit privileges) to leave it as a comment—although the latter is presumably less useful for stopping users from following an apparently legitimate link to a now-undesireable target.